# difference of each codes for wordpress

Tags: constants

I'm studying wordpress development and i was bumped to this codes. i'm trying my best to look from google but i can't seem to find it. Just wondering if what these codes means.

1. what does the /admin stands for in the theme_css_uri?

   ```
   define( 'name_THEME_URI',                       get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
   define( 'name_THEME_TEMPLATE_URI',              name_THEME_URI . '/templates' );
   define( 'name_THEME_LANGUAGES_URI',             name_THEME_URI . '/languages' );
   define( 'name_THEME_ASSETS_URI',                name_THEME_URI     . '/assets' );
   define( 'name_THEME_JS_URI',                    name_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/js' );
   define( 'name_THEME_CSS_URI',                   name_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/css' );
   define( 'name_THEME_IMAGES_URI',                name_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/images' );
   define( 'name_THEME_ADMIN_JS_URI',              name_THEME_JS_URI . '/admin' );
   define( 'name_THEME_ADMIN_CSS_URI',             name_THEME_CSS_URI . '/admin' );
   ```

2.what does the two dollar sign means and why does the code changed from get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); to $name_template_directory_uri

```
 $name_template_directory_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

 function name_register_js() {

global $name_template_directory_uri;
wp_register_script('nectar_priority', $name_template_directory_uri . '/js/priority.js', 'jquery', '',TRUE);

} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'name_register_js');
```

Hope someone can help me. 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, check how [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) works on PHP. It defines a named constant, `/admin` is just a folder, in this case, it's a folder that you have creatied to save JS files that are admin-related, that folder is located on `name_THEME_ASSETS_URI` which you previously defined as well as: `name_THEME_ASSETS_URI . '/js'`, so `/admin` is a folder inside `/js` which is inside of  `/templates` which is inside of your theme directory.
2. The dollar sign means, it's a variable, I recommend you to read a couple of basic PHP tutorials to give you a better understanding of those basic concepts.

While `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is a function, so please, read about [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp) and [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp) on PHP. It's a good start.

In general, it's highly recommended that you learn **PHP**, since WordPress is written in PHP and you will get lost fast if you don't know PHP, so I'd suggest you take a few days to learn that language and then come back to WordPress and you will understand everything more easily.